# How to reduce the speed of ScaleTo property apply to the image in Xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

In my project I have applying 'ScaleTo' property to the image, it's work nice but it applying very fast. I need to apply ScaleTo property slowly i.e when I apply ScaleTo property from (0, 2000) it will apply to the image within 5 milliseconds but what my requirement is need to apply that effect slowly upto 2 seconds. Please suggest any idea. Thank in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could see there is another parameter for the duration in the ScaleTo if you see it again. 
It's default value. That's probably why you couldn't use it.

Comment: Thanks Bright, I have double check that but I think that one represent the how much time we need to apply the 'ScaleTo' property but what my requirement reduced the speed of applying 'ScaleTo' property to image.

Comment: I have face another issue with that lee i.e when I apply 'ScaleTo' to the image it's resized then after how can I get image into previous size.

Comment: public Task<bool> ScaleTo(double scale, uint length=250, Easing easing=null)

Comment: That's my ScaleTo method from Xamarin.forms. When I typing Scaleto... on the any XF views, this shows up.

Comment: You can simply get it back to original size by using 'yourview.Scale = 1.0'